# SQLPLUS query output to *.csv format using java

Tags: java, oracle

I'm trying to convert SQLPLUS query output to *.csv format by using java code. On executing this spooler.sql on sqlplus getting error as `ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`
Can someone help me getting this resolved... knowing the fact that error is in spooler.sql file. Thanks in advance!!!
Following is my spooler.sql file code

```
SET LINESIZE 30000
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET SHOW OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET HEADING OFF
SET FEED OFF
SET ECHO OFF
SPOOL D:\CVS_test.csv
select regexp_substr (col_code, '[^,]+', 1,1) as "col_code_1" || ',' || regexp_substr (col_code, '[^,]+', 1,2) as "col_code_2" || ',' || col_status   
from temp_table left join TEMP_MSTR on temp_table.temp_org=TEMP_MSTR.mstr_org and temp_table.temp_acct = TEMP_MSTR.mstr_acct;
SPOOL OFF
EXIT
```

Comment: Those commands **only** work in SQLPlus you can't use them through JDBC/Java

Comment: Execute the `SELECT` statement and write the result to a file. What is stopping you from doing that? Executing SQL? Writing to a file? With a minimal amount of **research**, you can find examples of both on the web. Question down-voted for lack of research.

Comment: @Andreas I am facing this issue when using  regexp_substr (col_code, '[^,]+', 1,1) as "col_code_1" and without regexp_substr() my code is working fine.

Comment: Before converting any code to another language, you should make sure the original code actually works, otherwise the converted code won't work either. Are you asking us to help make the SQLPLUS query work? Or are you asking us to help convert to Java? *Hint:* One question per question, so you can't ask us both in a single question. --- Oh, and you're confused, because without `regexp_substr`, that code still wouldn't work. Use of `regexp_substr` is *not* the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After removing alias code is working

`select regexp_substr (col_code, '[^,]+', 1,1)|| ',' || regexp_substr (col_code, '[^,]+', 1,2) || ',' || col_status from temp_table left join TEMP_MSTR on temp_table.temp_org=TEMP_MSTR.mstr_org and temp_table.temp_acct = TEMP_MSTR.mstr_acct;`